# How to create a table by using h5py?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am a python learner, now at the basic level. I need to know, how to create a table using h5py and pass 10000 values. 
Looking for quick assistance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please note that this is not a software development service, try to learn more about the topic you need, try out some code and if you have specific questions come back here for assistance. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about what topics can be asked here! Good luck!

Comment: Happy Ganesh Chaturthi sir.

Answer (score 0):

That ought to get you started

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

file = h5py.File('quick.h5', 'w')

arr = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, 10000)
dset = file.create_dataset("data", (len(arr),), h5py.h5t.NATIVE_DOUBLE)
dset[...]=arr
```

Don't hesitate to download [HDFview](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/) to explore your h5 file.

And to learn about h5py visit https://www.h5py.org/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want / cannot migrate to [PyTables](https://www.pytables.org/) for a series of reasons, you could handle tables as Pandas `DataFrame`, get a `dict` out of it and use [`hdfdict`](https://pypi.org/project/hdfdict/) to dump / load the dictionary to / from HDF5 file:

```py
import h5py as h5
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import hdfdict

note = 'Just to create an attribute to the table'

data = {
    "Col 1": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "Col 2": np.random.random_sample(6).tolist(),
    "Col 3": ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
}

def write_data():
    with h5.File('test.h5', 'w') as f:
        table_group = f.require_group('MyTable')
        table_group.attrs['note'] = note
        hdfdict.dump(data, table_group)

def read_data():
    with h5.File('test.h5', 'r', libver='latest') as f:
        table_group = f['MyTable']
        note = table_group.attrs['note']
        print('Table Note: ', note)
        print('Table Data: ')
        df = pd.DataFrame(dict(hdfdict.load(table_group)))
        print(df)

write_data()
read_data()
```

This will return:

```
Table Note:  Just to create an attribute to the table
Table Data: 
   Col 1     Col 2 Col 3
0      1  0.878225  b'A'
1      1  0.816406  b'B'
2      1  0.388557  b'C'
3      2  0.242075  b'D'
4      2  0.428509  b'E'
5      2  0.887878  b'F'
```

NOTE: You could also use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=pandas%20to_hdf), but be aware that `pandas` uses `PyTables` as backend. I personally prefer not to mix things up, expecially if you're using tools like `SWMR` for which it seems that PyTables has not suppor. **What in the note might not be accurate**, since it comes from rapid and not intensive search; any correction to this information is very very welcome